# Django: correct way to group a bunch of media's

Tags: python, django, django-forms, media

I send several forms to a template, and I want to put all required media in the `<head>` tag. Some forms might require the same media (for instance, the same JS file), so I would like to unify all medias before putting them in the `<head>`. Question is, how do I do that? I know you can unify two medias by doing `m1 + m2`, but this will look ugly in the generic case where I have an unknown number of forms. Is there some shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I could find was doing it using list comprehensions and `reduce`:

```
media = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [form.media for form in forms])
```

Wonder if there's an easier way...

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you just use `{{ form.media }}` for each form, and link up the media in the form's `Meta`? I seem to remember that making sure that it didn't insert anything twice, but it's been a while.

Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I am not sure I understand - what do yo mean by " link up the media in the form's Meta"?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - it looks like there's a `Media` class you want to use (and are using): http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/